# SQLite3: How to concatenate a message for SELECT RAISE() in a trigger?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Using `SELECT RAISE()` from an SQLite3 trigger does not always provide sufficient context to debug the malformed SQL.  I would like to provide a more detailed error message.

The most obvious attempt does not work:

```
SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'test' || 'ing')
```

When installing the trigger, SQLite3 rejects with the error message: `near "||": syntax error`

This [old sqlite-users mailing list message from 2007](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/String-concatenation-disallowed-within-a-RAISE-function-td19985.html) recommends:

```
SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, ERROR_TEXT) FROM (SELECT 'test' || 'ing' ERROR_TEXT);
```

... but it does not work for me.  SQLite3 does not reject, but the trigger error message is `Error: near line 95: ERROR_TEXT`.

Any ideas?

FYI: I am working on Debian Linux (sid -- bleeding edge) with a very recent version of SQLite3: 3.8.7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RAISE function does not accept an expression; the second parameter must be a constant string (or identifier).

It is not possible to have a dynamic error message.

Answer (score 1):

*The answer is still **no** :(, but I'm hoping that this tip may help someone.*

I'm using SQLite 3.8.6 on Android.

You cannot concatenate the result like:

```
select RAISE(ABORT, 'Cannot change Item(' || old._id || ').parent nullity: '
    || ifNULL(old.parent, 'NULL')
    || ' -> '
    || ifNULL(new.parent, 'NULL')
where (old.parent is null) <> (new.parent is null);
```

but you can explode the conditions to be more specific (having multiple `RAISE`s in one `TRIGGER`:

```
select RAISE(ABORT, 'Cannot change Item.parent nullity: NULL -> NOT NULL!')
where old.parent is null and new.parent is not null;

select RAISE(ABORT, 'Cannot change Item.parent nullity: NOT NULL -> NULL!')
where old.parent is not null and new.parent is null;
```

However this doesn't really help the problem of, say, wanting to put the `Item._id` into the error message.

Comment: Three years later, I think the answer still "No", but hoping someone will prove me wrong...